# How to propagate traceId/correlationId to new Threads using Sleuth when using a third party library?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, mdc

We have a Spring boot micro-service which uses a third party library that internally creates a ThreadPoolExecutor and creates new threads for parallel processing tasks. When using distributed log tracing with Spring Cloud Sleuth, the propagation of traceId/correlationId does not work when new threads are created by the library (works fine when no new threads are created). We have no control over how the ThreadPoolExecutor is created or how the threads are invoked since it is a third party library code. Is there a good way to get around this issue?

I have tried wrapping the call to the third-party library with SpanInScope (as below), but as expected, it didn't work:-

```
@Autowired Tracer tracer;
...
...
final Span span = this.tracer.nextSpan();
try (final Tracer.SpanInScope ws = this.tracer.withSpan(span.start())) {
  try (final BaggageInScope correlationId = this.tracer.createBaggage("correlationid", "xyz")) {
    // call to the third-party library 
    .....
  }
} finally {
  span.end();
}
```

We do not have control over how the ThreadPoolExecutor is created, thus cannot use LazyTraceExecutor or LazyTraceThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

(Versions used: spring-boot 2.7.7, spring-cloud-sleuth 3.1.5)